# Archiving old data in Gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, archive

I have a gridview that will have certain columns like dates and status that will be edited by my users daily.  Is there a way to archive or save those entries daily and then have a button that will display a popup window or a temporary gridview row with the archived values.

I saw some posts that did a similar thing with mysql but not sure how to apply this to my situation, here is what I found:

```
 "select * from table1 where DATE < now() - interval 1 year" -u myuser -pxxxxxxxxx mydatabase > mydumpfile.txt

delete from your_table where `date` < now() - interval 1 year
```

Instead of this example though I would save that old data every day if changed in the archived table and retrieve that saved data if the user chooses.

So basically, I need help to do the following:

- Archive certain grid cells (date, status, etc...) each day when edited
- Save those archived items for a month (but can change the length depending on need)
- have a button in/for the gridview that when pressed will display

Any hints in the right direction to accomplish this would be great.

Comment: You know exactly what you need. Can you be more specific with which thing you need help?

Comment: I need help with the actual sql query and code to complete the task. Is there a specific way to archive data in sql? and then once its archived how can I display that archived data within the gridview with the current data.